# How can i handle Microsoft LDM data

Tags: partitioning

i install ubuntu dual-boot with windows in my ssd with separate partion and i have another hhd that contain a lot of my media data how can i access it in ubuntu os

i try to find some way to help but nothing helpful

i already try to use ldmtool but ldmtool scan show some kind like this

```
ldm> scan /dev/sda*
Error scanning /dev/sda: Error opening /dev/sda for reading: Permission denied
Error scanning /dev/sda1: Error opening /dev/sda1 for reading: Permission denied
Error scanning /dev/sda2: Error opening /dev/sda2 for reading: Permission denied
Error scanning /dev/sda3: Error opening /dev/sda3 for reading: Permission denied
Error scanning /dev/sda4: Error opening /dev/sda4 for reading: Permission denied
Error scanning /dev/sda5: Error opening /dev/sda5 for reading: Permission denied
Error scanning /dev/sda6: Error opening /dev/sda6 for reading: Permission denied
Error scanning /dev/sda7: Error opening /dev/sda7 for reading: Permission denied
[
]
ldm> scan /dev/sda
Error scanning /dev/sda: Error opening /dev/sda for reading: Permission denied
[
]
ldm> scan /dev/sdb
Error scanning /dev/sdb: Error opening /dev/sdb for reading: Permission denied
[
]
```

this was the output of command lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop1    7:1    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop2    7:2    0 140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop3    7:3    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop4    7:4    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop5    7:5    0  12.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop6    7:6    0   3.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
loop7    7:7    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop8    7:8    0    21M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop9    7:9    0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop10   7:10   0   1.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop11   7:11   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    99M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   117G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  15.6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0  14.9G  0 part /
└─sda7   8:7    0  84.8G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0    15M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0   790M  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   741G  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0 189.2G  0 part
```

it has 3 partition in sdb5 and freespace in sdb6

also this was the output of mount

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3512508k,nr_inodes=878127,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=715072k,mode=755)
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=41,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1445)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_103.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/103 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4917.snap on /snap/core/4917 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-26-1604_70.snap on /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-calculator_180.snap on /snap/gnome-calculator/180 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_51.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_69.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/69 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_36.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4486.snap on /snap/core/4486 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_25.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/25 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-26-1604_59.snap on /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-calculator_154.snap on /snap/gnome-calculator/154 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_37.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/37 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=715068k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

what should i do? can some one help me?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to add the output of the commands `lsblk` and `mount`. [`ldmtool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html) is _a tool to manage Microsoft Windows dynamic disks_. Do you use them? Please also provide the command line you used to launch `ldmtool`.

Comment: ah, i try to mount my partition that been in dynamic disk  mode, i hear that we can use ldmtool to handle is but the first thing to do is scan the disk and use it for the next step. but idmtool just show nothing after scan so, i don't how to do next, any idea with it  or did you have another way to fix it